# Best way to dynamically change aria-checked value

Tags: reactjs, boolean, state

For the code below I want to fire an onClick event and change the `aria-checked` value from `false` to `true` as you click from item 1 to 2 to 3, with the previous one becoming false as you click the next. What's the best way to do it?

```
render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div aria-checked={this.state.checked}>item 1</div>
          <div aria-checked={this.state.checked}>item 2</div>
          <div aria-checked={this.state.checked}>item 3</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

in my `constructor` I initialized state to `this.state = ({ checked: false })`

Comment: are you asking about how to register a click listener?  or how to use one field of your state to control the props of three different items?

Comment: how to use one field of your state to control the props of multiple items

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same value `this.state.checked` as the props for all the items, so if the value is `true`, of course all of them will be checked. What you need to store, is the index of the item currently checked.

It will be something like:

```
changeCheckedIndex = i => {
  this.setState({ checkedIndex: i });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => this.changeCheckedIndex(0)} aria-checked={this.state.checkedIndex === 0}>item 1</div>
      <div onClick={() => this.changeCheckedIndex(1)} aria-checked={this.state.checkedIndex === 1}>item 2</div>
      <div onClick={() => this.changeCheckedIndex(2)} aria-checked={this.state.checkedIndex === 2}>item 3</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```